# UMVU for $\sigma ^ p$ normal distribution.

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

I am having some trouble with the following problem:
let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ independent from a Normal distribution with unknown mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Find the UMVU estimator for $\sigma^p$ where $p>0$ is real.
I have found the maximum likelihood estimator but was not able to find and correct its mean, so I do not know how to proceed. (I have also tried to use Rao-Blackwell theorem but I did not know which unbiased estimator to use).
Thank you for your help.

Comment: If I find the MLE then I know it is a function of complete sufficient statistics (property of MVE), then if I can trasnsform it to make it unbiased I will have an unbiased estimator which is a function of complete sufficient statistic and therefore it is umvue because of the lehman-scheffe theorem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $\overline X=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n X_k$ and $S^2=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n (X_k-\overline X)^2$.

Then a complete sufficient statistic for $(\mu,\sigma^2)$ is given by $(\overline X, S^2)$.

By Lehmann-Scheffe theorem, any unbiased estimator of $\sigma^p$ based on $(\overline X, S^2)$ will be the UMVUE of $\sigma^p$.

Recall that $$\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2}\sim \chi^2_{n-1}$$

So,

\begin{align}
E\left[\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2}\right]^{p/2}&=\frac{1}{2^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\Gamma\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)}\int_0^\infty t^{p/2}\,e^{-t/2}\,t^{\frac{n-1}{2}-1}\,\mathrm{d}t
\end{align}

Simplifying both sides of the above equation you will finally arrive at $$E\left[cS^p\right]=\sigma^p$$

for some function $c(.)$ of $n$ and $p$.

Thus the UMVUE of $\sigma^p$ is $c(n,p) S^p$.

Comment: The UMVUE is just a function of $S^{2}$ and not the Complete Sufficient statistic $T(X)=(\overline{X},S^{2})$, now by taking a function $g(x,y)=y$, we can argue that the UMVUE would be a function of the Complete Sufficient statistic $T(X)$, but it does not look convincing as the information about $\mu$ in $\overline{X}$ is lost by just taking $S^{2}$. Further is it was true then,  $S^{2}$ would be the best-unbiased estimator of $\sigma^{2}$ but the answer above suggests something different. I am not quite sure how to resolve this doubt I am facing, any thoughts on this @StubbornAtom?

Comment: @Smokey $\overline X$ is already there when you define $S^2$. And $S^2$ as defined here *is* the best unbiased estimator of $\sigma^2$ when $\mu$ is unknown.

Comment: The value of $c(n,2)$ is not equal to 1 so $S^2$ is not best unbiased for $\sigma^2$ when $\mu$ is unknown.

Comment: It is true that $S^{2}$ is dependent on $\overline{X}$, however given a value of $S^{2}$, it is impossible to obtain a value of  $\overline{X}$ without knowledge of ordered statistics ${X_{(i)}}$, hence for a sample, the **combined** knowledge of $(\overline{X},S^{2}) $ is necessary to obtain a inference about the parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$

Comment: @Smokey $S^2=(0,1)^t(\overline X,S^2)$, a function of $T$. And $c(n,2)$ does equal $1$ by my calculations.

Comment: oh..apologies for not seeing that, and I was making an error in my calculations. Thanks for clearing this up @StubbornAtom.